# Is it safe to drop and create clustered indexes to move tables into a new data filegroup?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently in the process of splitting our database files into multiple, smaller, database filegroups as part of a SQL upgrade.

The pages I have been reading suggest that you move the clustered index with this script

```
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX <name of the existing clustered index> 
    ON <Table_name> (<Column1, Column2,…>) 
    WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON) 
    ON [<TargetFileName>]
```

This does not work:
`The new index definition does not match the constraint being enforced by the existing index.`

Navigating in SSMS to Server> Database > Tables > TableName > Constraints shows there are no constraints.

I have worked around this problem by navigating to Server> Database > Tables > TableName > Indexes, finding the Clustered Index, and then Script As DROP AND CREATE, which gives me this:

```
    USE [DatabaseName]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Index [TableName$0]    Script Date: 04/30/2019 11:01:06 ******/
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableName]') AND name = N'TableName$0')
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] DROP CONSTRAINT [TableName$0]
    GO

    USE [DatabaseName]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Index [TableName$0]    Script Date: 04/30/2019 11:01:06 ******/
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD  CONSTRAINT [TableName$0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [FieldName] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]
    GO
```

I change "ON [Data Filegroup 1]" to my new Filegroup, and it works. Everything *seems* fine, but I want to check I'm OK to do it this way.

Comment: Safe? Yes. Also horribly inefficient, because it first converts the whole table to a heap, then recreates it as clustered. You get the error because the PK is unique, and you didn't specify that -- use `CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX .. WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)`.

Comment: You aren't kidding!

Thank you, this works beautifully. Your method took 2 minutes to move a table, mine took 45.